# Cant understand how this blazor function works c#

Tags: c#, blazor

So im new to C# and this is rly confusing me. I got a .blazor class containing the HTML for my page. and it looks like this.

```
@page "/stations"

<h3>Stations</h3>
<div class="md-form mt-0"><input class="form-control" id="search_bar" placeholder="Search..." @oninput="@SearchProducts"></div>

@*https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1*@
@*https://scottsauber.com/2019/03/25/blazor-implementing-client-side-search-as-you-type-using-bind-value-oninput/*@

<i class="fas fa-edit" style="font-size:12px;"></i>
<i class="fa fa-car"></i>

@if (StationsList != null && FilteredStations != null)
{
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Station Name</th>
            <th>Service Location Name</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var station in FilteredStations)
        {


            if (station != null)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@station.Id</td>
                    <td>@station.Name</td>
                    <td>@station.ServiceLocationName</td>
                    <td class="edit-svg-icon"></td>
                    <NavLink class="nav-link">
                        <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true" id="@station.Id" @onclick="@(async () => await DeleteProduct(station.Id))" style="cursor: pointer"></span> Edit @*FIX ME should link to edit product. Obviously...*@
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink class="nav-link">
                        <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true" id="@station.Id" @onclick="@(async () => await DeleteProduct(station.Id))" style="cursor: pointer"></span> Delete
                    </NavLink>

                </tr>
            }

        }
    </table>
}
else
{
    <div class="lds-spinner"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
}
```

And then i got the .blazor.cs class containing my c# functions that i use in the .blazor file and it looks like this.

```
namespace Aftermarket.Server.AdministrationService.Client.Pages.ProductsPages
{
    public partial class ListStations
    {
        [Inject]
        public IStationService StationService { get; set; }
        public static string SearchString { get; set; } = "";
        protected static IEnumerable<StationsVM> StationsList { get; set; }
        public ElementReference Search_bar { get; set; }
        public static List<StationsVM> FilteredStations { get; set; }
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            StationsList = (await StationService.GetStations()).ToList();
            FilteredStations = new List<StationsVM>(StationsList);
        }
        //What makes the list go back to normal when a search is done and u delete search word?

        static public void SearchProducts(ChangeEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            string search = eventArgs.Value.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(search);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(search);
                FilteredStations.Clear();
                try
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(FilteredProductList + " FilteredProductList is initialized??");
                    foreach (var item in StationsList)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());

                        bool stationFound = false;
                        if (item.Name != null)
                        {
                            if (item.Name.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()))
                            {
                                stationFound = true;
                            }
                        }

                        if (item.ServiceLocationName != null && stationFound != true)
                        {
                            if (item.ServiceLocationName.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()))
                            {
                                stationFound = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (stationFound != true && item.Id != null)
                        {
                            if (item.Id.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()))
                            {
                                stationFound = true;
                            }
                        }

                        if (stationFound)
                        {
                            FilteredStations.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message + "   InnerException");
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString() + "    ToString");
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Source);

                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        public async Task<EventCallback> DeleteProduct(long id)
        {
            await StationService.DeleteStation(id.ToString());
            StationsList = (await StationService.GetStations()).ToList();
            FilteredStations = new List<StationsVM>(StationsList);
            return new EventCallback();
        }
    }
}
```

When i load my page (the .blazor class) it checks the FilteredStations and since that contains all my stations it list all my stations. But then when I do a search we see in the .blazor.cs class that the first thing it does is to clear the FilteredStations list. and then goes on to add what ever you search for to it. Now all this is fine except if i after a search clear the searchbar it then gives me a full list of stations again. Now i understand this is how its supposed to work but how ?? If it clears the FilteredStations when you do a search and never repopulates it again how can it then read from it and populate the page with all stations again after i clear the search bar??

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum. "Please explain to me how someone else's code works" is off topic.

Comment: At first FilteredStations=StationsList, when you change the input, clear FilteredStation, loop over StationList and add (see the instruction: `FilteredStations.Add(item);`) the elements that meet the condition

Answer (score 1):

I didn’t find an obvious reason to that. Maybe The if clause is checking an empty string and this can make The bool retuns true and it will be added in your last statements.

I would suggest you to use linq. It will make your code cleaner and it’s very powerfull to work with lists.

Var filteredItens = itens.where( it => it.name.contains(SearchTerm).toList();

I’m using generic code ‘couse i’m using The phone.